# How to preserve the punctuation when converting words to Pig Latin?

Tags: java

I've been working on a Java program to convert English words to Pig Latin. I've done all the basic rules such as appending -ay, -way, etc., and special cases like question -> estionquay, rhyme -> ymerhay, and I also dealt with capitalization (Thomas -> Omasthay). However, I have one problem that I can't seem to solve: I need to preserve before-and-after punctuation. For example, What? -> Atwhay? Oh!->Ohway! "hello" -> "ellohay" and "Hello!" -> "Ellohay!" This is not a duplicate by the way, I've checked tons of pig latin questions and I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

Here is my code so far (I've removed all the punctuation but can't figure out how to put it back in):

```
public static String scrub(String s)
{
 String punct = ".,?!:;\"(){}[]<>";
 String temp = "";
 String pigged = "";
 int index, index1, index2, index3 = 0;

 for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
 {
  if(punct.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == -1) //if s has no punctuation
  {
   temp+= s.charAt(i);
  }
 } //temp equals word without punctuation
 pigged = pig(temp); //pig is the piglatin-translator method that I have already written, 
 //didn't want to put it here because it's almost 200 lines

 for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++)
 {
  if(s.indexOf(punct)!= -1)//punctuation exists
   {
    index = x; 
   }
 }
}
```

I get that in theory you could search the string for punctuation and that it should be near the beginning or end, so you would have to store the index and replace it after it is "piglatenized", but I keep getting confused about the for loop part. if you do index = x inside the for-loop, you're just replacing index every time the loop runs. 
Help would be appreciated greatly! Also, please keep in mind I can't use shortcuts, I can use String methods and such but not things like Collections or ArrayLists (not that you'd need them here), I have to reinvent the wheel, basically. **By the way, in case it wasn't clear, I already have the translating-to-piglatin thing down. I only need to preserve the punctuation before and after translating.**

Comment: Are you passing a single word or sentence into this function?

Comment: A single word, thankfully

Comment: Do you want to take punctuation out of the middle of the word or just the exact beginning and/or end?

Comment: @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski If it's in the middle of the word when it's in English, then I want the same punctuation to be in the same place in the PigLatin word. For example, Ap!ple should be Ap!pleway, and What! should be Atwhay! with the exclamation mark in the same place as it originally was.

Comment: What if it was w!hat, should it read atw!hay or a!twhay? If you want it the first way then you can treat the punctuation as part of the consonant cluster so you don't have to know the position.

Comment: The ap!ple example was a bad one. I meant it should adhere to the rules of normal punctuation, such as "hello" or What!

Comment: But it's alright, I came up with a complicated solution to fix it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use regular expressions, you can use the following code.

```
String pigSentence(String sentence) {
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+").matcher(sentence);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(pig(m.group()));
  }
  m.appendTail();
  return sb.toString();
}
```

In plain English, the above code is:

```
for each word in the sentence:
  replace it with pig(word)
```

But if regular expressions are forbidden, you can try this:

```
String pigSentence(String sentence) {
  char[] chars = sentence.toCharArray();
  int i = 0, len = chars.length;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  while (i < len) {

    while (i < len && !Character.isLetter(chars[i]))
      sb.append(chars[i++]);
    int wordStart = i;

    while (i < len && Character.isLetter(chars[i]))
      i++;
    int wordEnd = i;

    if (wordStart != wordEnd) {
      String word = sentence.substring(wordStart, wordEnd - wordStart);
      sb.append(pig(word));
    }
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is: remove punctuation if it exists, convert to pig latin, add punctuation back.

Assuming punctuation is always and the end of the string, You can check for punctuation with the following:

```
String punctuation = "";
for (int i = str.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) {
        punctuation = str.charAt(i) + punctuation;
    } else {
        break; // Found all punctuation
    }
}
str = str.substring(0, str.length() - punctuation.length()); // Remove punctuation
// Convert str to pig latin
// Append punctuation to str
```

Comment: Always at the end, as in beginning and end, or just the end of the string?

Comment: End of the string.  (e.g. Hello!! -> Hello, !Hello! -> !Hello)

Comment: But my problem is how to append it in the same place, and that wasn't included in your answer

Comment: You didn't provide the code that shows how you put the string back together so it's a little difficult figuring out what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd find it troublesome to handle punctuation separate from the translation. For punctuation at the very beginning or very end, you can save them and tag them back on after translating.

But if you remove the punctuations from the middle of the word, it will be rather difficult to replace them back to their correct location. Their indices change from the original word to the pigged word, and by a variable amount. (For some a random example, consider "Hel'lo" and "Quest'ion". The apostrophe shifts left by either 1 or 2, and you won't know which.)

How does your translation method handle punctuation? Do you really need to remove all punctuation before passing it to the translator? I'd suggest having your pigging method handle at least the punctuation in the middle of the word.